# how to hide by default the menu bar from terminal on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint

In the previous version I had just to right-click or click in **View** menu and uncheck 'Show Menubar'. But now in this new version I had to do this every time I start the terminal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit -> profile preferences -> general -> show menubar by default in new terminals